# Adding Fresco Library breaks Android project

Tags: android, fresco

I have an Android project. It's working for several iteration now without any major issues. It's important to note that I am using a 3rd party library that uses an `.so` file in jnilib folder.

I decided to add WebP and GIF playback implementation. Upon looking for 3rd party libraries, I ended up using Fresco.

Now, I tried adding Fresco in gradle and I immediately encountered an issue with `Duplicate Entry`. Perhaps because of Facebook SDK implementation. I managed to fix by adding `exclude` for `com.parse.bolts`

The gradle build now works properly, but as soon as I run the app. I encountered an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with the code from the library I mentioned earlier

Anybody encountered this issue? How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

Here's the error log

```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.lib.util.Utils.nativeSetLevel(int) (tried Java_com_lib_util_Utils_nativeSetLevel and Java_com_lib_util_Utils_nativeSetLevel)`
```

That code works before. This only happen when I add Fresco.

Comment: Describe error more precisely.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev sorry for being vague. Added the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably that's because fresco added native libraries of new architecture (which was unsupported by your libs, for example arm64-v8a), try to limiting supported architectures adding

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

into defaultConfig of your build gradle, changing `"armeabi-v7a", "x86"` to the list of architectures, which you build your lib for.

Another way is to build your native library for all architectures, supported by fresco.

Comment: ok i see. that might be the problem. the library I'm using only supports arm architecture. will try the gradle solution, thanks for the help.